# Pytest-3.3.2 using python 2.7

Tags: ubuntu, pytest, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have just installed Ubuntu for WSL, mainly to be able to use linux commands while i learn coding in python, and in particular git and pytest.
I installed pytest using the bash shell, and even though i have python 3.7 installed, when running pytest, it uses python 2.7:

Python 2.7.15rc1, pytest-3.3.2

when running pytest from windows CMD, it runs a different version of pytest python 3.7

Python 3.7.0, pytest-3.10.0

i realise this could be a very stupid question, but this is my first foray into linux based apps, and i would like to know how i can run pytest with the latest python version from the bash shell. I read some posts and have already tried:

python3 -m pytest

python3.7 -m pytest

but get the following message:

/usr/bin/python3: No module named pytest

Can somebody help me please?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

thank you

in fact i did the following and it worked:

- apt install python 3 pip
- sudo apt install python3-test

after that, it will refer to the latest python version when calling pytest

- python -m pytest -v

Answer (score 0):

First check if the pytest in installed in the system or not by giving the commnad :
pytest -v.
If it returns in below manner:
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.17, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /usr/bin/python2

which means pytest is being installed but not matching with current version of python3.

To run with the current Python3 version on system:
python -m pytest -v TestCases/Test_CreateUser.py

where TestCases is the directory in my project & giving path to respective file for run.
Following is the output.

platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /home/rohitdalmia/PythonBasics/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/rohitdalmia/PythonBasics
collected 1 item

TestCases/Test_CreateUser.py::test_create_new_user PASSED